# Newtonsoft.JSON Serialization Array, Object, or Null

Tags: c#, json.net

I have some JSON that can be a List or null. How do I create a POCO for this JSON?

Here is an example array:
http://pastebin.com/qAZF2Ug9

Here is my POCO:
http://pastebin.com/hUtgyytc

How can I tell Newtonsoft.JSON to ignore the SalesLine object, if it is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the [settings](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/SerializationSettings.htm):

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings {
    NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore};
```

and use that in various serializer constructors and serialize calls.

Alternatively, IIRC it supports [conditional serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm), i.e.

```
public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { return Foo != null; }
// pairs to property Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to mark this property with [JsonProperty attribute](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm)

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public SaleLines SaleLines { get; set; }
```